# Why is Scroll Percentage more than 100

Tags: javascript, scroll

I am using this method to calculate Scroll Percentage (after reading a bunch of posts online). However, when I scroll to the very bottom the scroll percentage goes to > 100%. The values are:

Scroll values: ScrollHeight: 3405 scrollBarHeight:  1408 scrollTop: 1997.3333740234375 scrollPercentage: 100.01669374178455

I want to understand why is this happening and if my approach is wrong?

thanks.

```
    // This is the container with the scrolbar. We are using this element as we want the inner div. document.documentElement is the full element
    const scrollingElement: HTMLElement = document.getElementById(personalInsightsContainerId);

    // If no scrollingElement is present, do not do anything.
    if (scrollingElement) {
        // The Element.scrollTop property gets or sets the number of pixels that the content of an element is scrolled upward.
        // An element's scrollTop is a form of distance measurement regarding an element's top to its topmost visible content.
        // When an element content does not generate a vertical Scrollbar, then its scrollTop value defaults to 0.
        const scrollTop: number = scrollingElement.scrollTop;

        // The difference b/w scrolling point.
        const scrollingDifference: number = scrollTop - this.lastScrollNumber;

        // We want to scroll if: a) there is scrollElement defined b) either the scrolling is first time or the scrollDifference is > 100.
        if (this.lastScrollNumber === 0 || scrollingDifference > 100) {
            // The Element.scrollHeight read-only property is a measurement of the height of an element's content,
            // Including content not visible on the screen due to overflow.
            const scrollHeight = scrollingElement.scrollHeight;

            // The HTMLElement.offsetHeight read-only property is the height of the element including vertical padding and borders, as an integer.
            const scrollBarHeight = scrollingElement.offsetHeight;

            if (scrollHeight && scrollBarHeight) {
                this.lastScrollNumber = scrollTop;

                 const totalHeight = scrollHeight - scrollBarHeight;
                 const scrollPercentage = totalHeight > 0 ? (scrollTop / totalHeight) * 100 : -1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Fundamentally, you're getting a value very slightly greater than 1 in `(scrollTop / totalHeight)`.

Comment: this is one concrete example where I am able to repro and get the value. But there are other cases where values are far bigger - so that is why it is a concern.

Answer (score 0):

try to use clientHeight instead of offsetHeight

Comment: IE6+ https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/clientHeight#Browser_compatibility

Comment: in my case clientHeight is the same as offsetheight.

Answer (score 0):

What browser do you use? In chrome/FF Element.scrollTop is always integer value. Try to use `const scrollTop: number = Math.floor(scrollingElement.scrollTop);`

Comment: I am using Chrome and Edge.